# I want to hide the header. It's hidden when using Expo Go, but when I release and build it as an APK and install it, the header becomes visible

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, eas

I'm encountering an issue with React Native navigation. When using Expo Go, the header is not visible, which is what I want. However, when I build the app as an APK using EAS Build and install it on a real device, the header is displayed.

App.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);

  return (

    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              display: 'none',
            },
            headerShown: false,
            header: null,
          }}
          initialRouteName={'SignIn'}
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Register"
            component={Register}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              header: () => null, // Hide the header for MainLayout
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              header: () => null, // Hide the header for MainLayout
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              header: () => null, // Hide the header for MainLayout
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="ForgotPassword"
            component={ForgotPassword}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              header: () => null, // Hide the header for MainLayout
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="MainLayout"
            component={MainLayout}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              header: () => null, // Hide the header for MainLayout
            }}
          />
         
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <FlashMessage
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          zIndex: 9999
        }}
        position="top" />
    </Provider>

  );
}


export default App
```

i use version

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
"expo": "^49.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
"react-native": "0.72.5",
```

[![This on expo go header is hide][1]][1]

[![build in .apk it show header, i testing on real device][2]][2]

**This on expo go header is hide**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PPam.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezXOr.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to customize StatusBar?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar/

Comment: can give me example code to hide?

Comment: Please create and share a repository with screens like you made. I will fix the problem and test it on my devices to be sure we achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving status bar color as transparent. I guess this issue you are facing is only with android and not ios.

Comment: try wrap screen with safearea

Answer (score 0):

i fix with add safearea and make status bar as transparant

example in app.js

```
import { SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

<SafeAreaProvider>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            display: 'none',
          },
          headerShown: false,
          headerMode: 'none'
        }}
        headerMode={'none'}
        initialRouteName={'SignIn'}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={Register}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    <FlashMessage
      position="top" />
  </Provider>

</SafeAreaProvider>
```

on another screen

```
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

   <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="light-content" />
        <ImageBackground source={source || images.background} style={styles.background}>
            {children}
        </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
```